# Error with Firestore security rules: FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

**Intended behavior**

The goal is to rework my security rules such that only an authenticated user can read and write the data of that specific user. This is based on the users UID, which is how we identify individual users (this is done from firebase authentication, so not sure what the problem is).

**The error**

FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions

Any suggestions on what I can do here would be very much appreciated. I haven't been able to find anything applicable in other questions asked.

Comment: When posting about security rules, your question should also contain the code from the client that is being rejected.  We need to be able to see that your rules match your query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify that subcollection in your rules

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid == userId;

      match /practitionerClients/{clientId} {
        allow read: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      }

    }
  }
}
```

Whenever you add a new sub-collection like that you should usually have to specify it or add a wildcard rule for that path. So instead of the above rule you could do this

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /users/{userId}/{document=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

you can read more [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#recursive_wildcards)

Answer (score 0):

Your rules don't match any documents.  You have to retain the match for `/databases/{database}/documents` that you were given in the initial set of rules, and as shown in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started).

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userId} {
     allow read: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey there! Thanks for responding :) 

I'm still getting an error — here is the error

sign-up-new.js:2740 Error writing document:  FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.
    at new t (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.2.4/firebase-firestore.js:1:47216)
    at https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.2.4/firebase-firestore.js:1:356293
    at lr.<anonymous> (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.2.4/firebase-firestore.js:1:355526)
    at qt (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.2.4/firebase-firestore.js:1:14255)
    at lr.c.dispatchEvent

Comment: Please edit the question to include all the relevant details - don't leave them in comments, as they are difficult to read.  As as I said in my other comment, you should include the source code that shows the query you're trying to make.

Comment: Your code is trying to query documents in a subcollection. You will need to write rules to match that subcollection as well. The userId wildcard does not match recursively.  I strongly suggest reading through the documentation to learn how rules work. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure

Answer (score 0):

For any persons who still face this issue.
If you have subcollection in ff, you may try this option.
please allow everyone/auth user to read the subcollection.

How to do that?
go to data >> find setting symbol >> scroll down till you meet crud table >> check to allow read >> deploy rules

if you want to undo the rules, just visit firebase or supabase and delete that version of rules.